# Program Execution + Parameters from a form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am currently trying to execute a program with a parameter in a C# form. The code I have:

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("nan.exe");

    }
```

Although I am trying to pass this parameter: "nan.exe C:\Windows\System32"

How could this me done in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
 Process.Start("nan.exe", @"c:\windows\system32");
```

Using Environment.GetFolderPath() is recommended.

Comment: Thanks, but can envorioment variable be used such as %TEMP% etc?

Comment: Yes, pass anything you want.  Like Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");

Comment: @Mike For that, you need to use the method `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`StartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx) object to do this for you:

```
// where fileName and arguments is what you need:
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"nan.exe", @"C:\windows\system32");
p.Start();
```